# How do setup a Samba4 share that does not require any user authentication on FreeBSD 10.x?

Tags: freebsd, samba, samba4

Since the share is only available on my local network, I would like to setup a share that requires no username/password.

I'm trying to map the share from my Mac Pro. I have no problems mapping the share with user authentication.

Thanks for the help/suggestions.

This is my smb4.conf

```
[global]
load printers = no
workgroup = myworkgroup

bind interfaces only = yes
interfaces = em0 em1
hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.3.0/24
hosts deny = all
security = user

log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
max log size = 1000
interfaces = em0 em1
passdb backend = tdbsam

dns proxy = no
min receivefile size=16384
socket options=IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
use sendfile=true

unix extensions = no
nt acl support = yes
inherit acls = no
map acl inherit = yes
vfs objects = zfsacl

[myshare]
path = /Volumes/storage
public = yes
mag to guest = Bad User
writable = yes
printable = no
create mask = 0664
directory mask = 0775
```

This is my folder setup. Guest should be able to list folder contents at least.

[image: ls screenshot]

Comment: `mag to guest` should be `map to guest`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add "guest ok = yes" (see https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTOK)